# Rsync only new files from a remote server

Tags: ssh, find, rsync

I have a remote server with an rsync share and I need to pull just the most recent 7 days of files.

I can SEND files based on date by using:

```
find /path -mtime 7 ... -exec rsync -a
```

but I can't just login to the server and send the files to my local machine so I need a way to use rsync to get all the files that are less than 7 days old and grab them.

I cannot simply sync everything as the total data on the server exceeds 100TB and I don't have access to the remote server other than the rsync module.

Comment: Wouldn't that run find locally? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you get a file listing including time stamps from the remote side? (If all else fails, you could `touch` dummy files locally and use `--ignore-existing` to not overwrite those files.)

Comment: I assume you have `ssh`-access when using rsync, so you could use `ssh backup@host "find <dir> <options>" > temp_file_list` and then use this list for `rsync`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, this can actually be done with `rsync(1)` alone, without shell access to the remote server.

Assuming `bash(1)` and GNU `date(1)`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

src=rsync://example.com/archives/
dst=/path/to/mirrors

cutoff=$( date -d '7 days ago' +%s )
rsync -na --no-motd --out-format='%M %f' "$src" "$dst" | \
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        d=${line%% *}
        fn=${line#* }
        fdate=$( date -d "${d/-/ }" +%s ) || continue
        if [ $fdate -ge $cutoff ]; then printf '%s\0' "$fn"; fi
    done | \
    rsync -a --files-from=- -0 "$src" "$dst"
```

Comment: I am getting file_stat errors and I can't figure out why. Given `src=rsync://server/files/4K/; dst=/local/4K/` I get errors like `rsync: link_stat "/4K/local/4K/folder one/File Name 4" (in files) failed: No such file or directory (2)` I mean, I understand the error Is because that path is invalid, but I don't understand how that path is getting mushed together like that.

Comment: @lbutlr As far as I can tell that's because of the trailing slash in `dst`. `rsync` does some bizarre dance with parsing trailing slashes.  To mirror directory `/files/4K` on the server to local directory `/local/4K` you need `src=rsync://server/files/4K/` (with trailing slash) and `dst=/local/4K` (without trailing slash).  That's probably all you need to remember, but there's a lot more about it in the manual.

Comment: Hmm. Took out the trailing slash and it looks the same. I wonder if the source server is using an old rsync. Does this require rsync 3.x?

Comment: @lbutlr No idea.  But your problem is `No such file or directory (2)`, not protocol mismatch, option unknown, or similar.  Perhaps a dangling symlink on the server?

Comment: The end of the path on the server "4K" is getting prepended to the path of the local share (/local/4K) and THAT is being passed to rsync along with the file path, which cannot find the file on the server, of course.

Comment: I had to add a `if [[ "$fn" == "." ]] ; then continue ; fi` in order to make it actually work, since on my ssh-based approach, the "./" was part of what was being recursively transferred.

Answer (score 5):

This is the approach that I used as part of an `rsnapshot` backup script:

```
rhost=user@backuphost
rpath=/path/to/files

ssh -qx "$rhost" "cd '$rpath' && find . -mtime -7 -print0" |
    rsync --from0 --files-from=- -avHS "$rhost:$rpath/" .
```